# C function by open a file and transfer the data

Tags: c

Here is the code 
The expect result will open a file and put data inside it .and show the data by reading the file .
i have test so many times but i also can't find mistake. but still can't run.

```
/*lab 9.2*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 40

int main(){
    int writeFile(char);
    char filename[MAX];
    char message[51];
    int num1;

    printf("Plz enter output file name: ");
    gets(filename);

    num1 = writeFile(filename);

    if (num1==1) {
        printf("Write File<%c> Finish OK!",filename);
    } else {
        printf("Write File<%c> Finish Fail!",filename);
    }

    return 0;
}


int writeFile(char gef)
{
    int i;  
    int data[6]={1,12,23,34,45,56};
    char message;
    char array1;
    FILE *checkicpfile;
    FILE *icpfile;
    int vaild;

    icpfile=fopen(filename,"w");
    fputs("icp\n321 6\n",icpfile);
    fclose(icpfile);

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {       
        addicpfile=fopen(filename,"a+");
        fprintf(addicpfile,"%d ",data[i]);
        fclose(addicpfile);
    }

    checkicpfile=fopen(filename,"r");

    if (checkicpfile != NULL) {
        fclose(checkicpfile);   
        numco = 1;
    } else {
        fclose(checkicpfile);  numco = 0;
    }

    if (numco==1) {
        printf("Write File<%s> Finish OK!",filename);
    } else {
        printf("Write File<%s> Finish Fail!",filename);
    }   
}
```

so i guess the function trans has a problems .thank you for your time to see this question.

Comment: The solution is to learn to use a debugger and step through your code, checking your logic (and the values of the variables) as you go along.

Comment: "can't run" - do you ask us to guess what does it mean? Does it compile? Does it print anything?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several problems. I'll be explaining them in order.

First of all,

```
int writeFile(char);
```

Should be changed to

```
int writeFile(char[]);
```

And should be placed outside `main`,just after the `#define MAX 40`. Then,

```
char message[51];
```

Is an unused variable . Remove it. Never use `gets` as it is dangerous and has been removed from the standard. Use `fgets` instead-

```
fgets(filename,sizeof filename,stdin);
```

Since you are passing an array of characters to the function,change

```
int writeFile(char gef)
```

To

```
int writeFile(char gef[])
```

You need to open the file once and then close it after writing. So change your function to-

```
int writeFile(char gef[])
{
    int i;
    int data[6]={1,12,23,34,45,56};
    FILE *file; //removed uneccessary variables

    if((file=fopen(gef,"w"))==NULL) //if opening the file failed,
    {       
        printf("An error occured");
        return 0; //end the function
    }
    fputs("icp\n321 6\n",file);

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {       
        fprintf(file,"%d ",data[i]);
    }
    fclose(file); //close the file
    return 1;
}
```

And finally,use `%s` instead of `%c` in

```
printf("Write File<%c> Finish OK!",filename);
```

And

```
printf("Write File<%c> Finish Fail!",filename);
```

As `filename` is a string and not a character. After you make the changes I told to do,your code will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

some problems:

- never use gets() for user input!
- always check the result of fopen()
- indent your code readable

Comment: ... and show us compilable code